# Why can't run expand, factor and simplify function Sympy in Excel + xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, vba, sympy, xlwings

Actually I can run Sympy scripts in Excel with xlwings.
    I haven't problems with limits, integrals, diff, solveset, etc..., but I can't run factor, expand, simplify and trigronometric expand. I suspect all this function are linked internally, because all them give me the same error:

```
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

The problem is only with factor, expand, simplify and trigonometric expand functions.

My code in VBA Excel:

```
    Function factor(func As String)
            If TypeOf Application.Caller Is Range Then On Error GoTo failed
            factor = Py.CallUDF("pruebasympy", "factor", Array(func), ThisWorkbook, Application.Caller)
            Exit Function
    failed:
            factor = Err.Description
    End Function
```

My code in Sympy script (pruebasympy.py):

```
    import xlwings as xw
    from sympy import *

    @xw.func
    @xw.arg('func')

    def factor(func):
        x = symbols('x')               
        return str(factor(func))
```

When in Excel put the expression (x**4)-1 into function "=Factor()", the error msg is:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I try with this lines, but don't work:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

Whats I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function calls itself endlessly. What did you expect to happen? Perhaps you should read up on how to use recursion correctly?

Comment: Thanks! Only change the name in script to Factorize and the function work.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that "RecursiveError" was a internal error in Sympy or xlwings. The error was use the same name of system function and the def function. Changing the def function name solve the problem.

Comment: And you may want to consider importing what you need instead of everything (`from sympy import *`). The import time of some SymPy modules is noticeable.